# How to set connection timeout in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to figure out how to set the connection timeout in `create_engine()`, so far I've tried:

```
create_engine(url, timeout=10)
```

> TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'timeout' sent to create_engine(), using configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check
>   that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of
>   components.

```
create_engine(url, connection_timeout=10)
```

> TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'connection_timeout' sent to
>   create_engine(), using configuration
>   PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword
>   arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'timeout': 10})
```

> (psycopg2.OperationalError) invalid connection option
>   "timeout"

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'connection_timeout': 10})
```

> (psycopg2.OperationalError) invalid connection option
>   "connection_timeout"

```
create_engine(url, pool_timeout=10)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The right way is this one (`connect_timeout` instead of `connection_timeout`):

```py
# NOTE: timeout units are seconds
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10})
```

...and it works with both Postgres and MySQL

[docs sqlalchemy connect-args](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#use-the-connect-args-dictionary-parameter)

Comment: What is the default value for the connect_timeout variable (in general and specific to MySQL database?

Comment: FWIW, this syntax is documented here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-args

Comment: Other timeouts I try are failing. For example, I would like to use net_read_timeout for mysql, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: and `timeout` for pymssql.

Comment: 10 what? Minutes or second or milliseconds?

Comment: @Ganesh Satpute seconds!

Comment: The list of available options for Postgres, like `connect_timeout`, seems to be documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

Comment: What happens to the connection if the computer runs out of memory, stalls the DB. Will the database be able to disconnect from the connection?

Comment: How to check the default value for the connect_timeout?

Comment: `TypeError: 'connect_timeout' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` doen't work on oracle

Comment: I confirm it works with MS SQL Server.
"This may be used for parameters that are otherwise not handled by the dialect when added to the query string, as well as when special sub-structures or objects must be passed to the DBAPI"
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#use-the-connect-args-dictionary-parameter

Answer (score 24):

For whoever is using **Flask-SQLAlchemy** instead of plain SQLAlchemy, you can choose between two ways for passing values to SQLAlchemy's `create_engine`:

1. Use `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` configuration key (Flask-SQLAlchemy>=2.4 required)

```
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    'connect_args': {
        'connect_timeout': 5
    }
}
```

2. Or, in alternative, use `engine_option` when instantiating `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(
    engine_options={ 'connect_args': { 'connect_timeout': 5 }}
)

db.init_app(app)
```

EDIT: The examples are using the `connect_timeout` argument that works (at least) for MySQL and PostgreSQL (value represent seconds), other DBMS may require different argument name to be passed to affect the connection timeout.  I suggest to check your DBMS manual to check for such option.

Answer (score 7):

In response to comment below by @nivhanin which asks "What is the default value for the connect_timeout variable (in general and specific to MySQL database?"? (I don't have enough reputation to leave comments).

Default for `connect_timeout` for Mysql5.7 is [10 seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout)

Also maybe relevant:

- `wait_timeout` -- [default value of 28800 seconds (8 hours)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)
- `interactive_timeout` -- [default value of 28800 seconds (8 hours)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)

Answer (score 7):

For **SQLite** 3.28.0:

```py
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'timeout': 1000})
```

will set the connection timeout to 1000 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

For `sqlite` backend:

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'connect_timeout': timeout})
```

will set the connection timeout to `timeout`.

Answer (score 2):

for **SQL Server** use the `Remote Query Timeout`:

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'Remote Query Timeout': 10})
```

default is 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you have a source for the default timeout being 5 seconds? [As far as I can see in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15), the default is 600 seconds, which is more in line with the kinds of errors I'm getting in my application.

Comment: Use `'remote login timeout'` for the connection timeout

Answer (score 1):

For a db2 backend via `ibm_db2_sa` + `pyodbc`:

I looked through the source code, and there seems to be no way to control the connection timeout as of version 0.3.5 (2019/05/30):
https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa

I'm posting this to save others the trouble of looking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this for binded **mssql+pyodbc** database and default **sqlite** and couldn't make any of above work.

What finally worked for me, was

```
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        'connect_args': {"timeout": 10}
    }
```

This is consistent with [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#use-the-connect-args-dictionary-parameter) as well

Comment: `TypeError: 'timeout' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` it doen't work on oracle

Comment: yes, it works for microsoft sql server + sqlite only.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: for SQL Server use 'remote login timeout':

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'remote login timeout': 10})
```

Thomasleveil posted on Jun 21, but it was buried in the comments, and was the only version that worked for me.