# How to keep session active for long time in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I have a code that runs a query from a query list. These query are long and take quite a long time to execute. Since I am executing these query in a loop, the session seems to expire and I get a error telling me that the connection to the server was lost.

Then I created the session as well as engine inside the loop (I closed the session and disposed the engine at the end of the loop.) I have understood that creating new connection is an expensive operation.

How can I re-use the connection in this case so that I do not have to create the session and engine each time?

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources
some_engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/')

# create a configured "Session" class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

# create a Session
session = Session()

for long_query in long_query_list:
    # work with sess
      session.execute(long_query)
      session.commit()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640726/how-to-set-connection-timeout-in-sqlalchemy.

Comment: Is it a good practice to set connect_timeout to a very large value?