# How to overcome the 2hr connection timeout (OperationalError) using SQLAlchemy and Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I'm trying to execute some long-running SQL queries using SQLAlchemy against a Postgres database hosted on AWS RDS.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn_str = 'postgresql://user:password@db-primary.cluster-cxf.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev'
engine = create_engine(conn_str)

sql = 'UPDATE "Clients" SET "Name" = NULL'
#this takes about 4 hrs to execute if run in pgAdmin
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sql)
```

After running for exactly 2 hours, the script errors out with

```
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I have tested setting connection timeouts in SQLAlchemy (based on [How to set connection timeout in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640726/how-to-set-connection-timeout-in-sqlalchemy)). This did not make a difference.

I have looked up the connection settings in the Postgres settings (based on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server), but both `statement_timeout` and `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` are set to 0, meaning there are no set limits.

Comment: How is that possible?  Even with a hundred million records, that should be a 10-second operation, not a 4-hour operation.

Comment: I just added a dummy example sql statement, the actual SQL statement is page-and-a-half long, but executes without any issues when run in pgAdmin/DBeaver. I don't think the specific SQL statement makes any difference to the issue at hand.

Comment: Some firewalls / routers may be configured to drop connections after a period of (what they perceive to be ) inactivity.

Comment: 2 hours sounds like a tcp timeout.  Try setting the tcp keep alive values.

Comment: @jjanes should these be set on the client running the python code or on the postgres server? if it's the latter, why would the SQL statement work without any issues in pgAdmin?

Comment: I think it could be done in either place, but don't have direct experience with this.  Maybe pgAdmin sets the tcp keep alives automatically.  Is it running on the same host as SQLalchemy is?

Comment: @jjanes yep, same host.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jjanes. This smells like a TCP connection timeout issue. Might be that somewhere in the network layer something, be it a NAT or a firewall, dropped your TCP connection, leaving the code to wait for the full TCP keepalive timeout until it sees the connection as closed. This could happen usually when the network topology between the client and the database is complicated. For example there may be a company firewall, or some sort of interconnection. pgAdmin may come with a pre-configured setting for TCP keepalive, therefore it was not impacted, but I'm not sure.

Other timeouts didn't kick in because, in my understanding, TCP timeout is in the L4 layer, which overshadows other timeouts that are in L7 application layer.

You could try adding the keepalive parameters into your connection string and see if it can resolve the issue. For example:

```
postgresql://user:password@db-primary.cluster-cxf.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev?keepalives_idle=1&keepalives_count=1&tcp_user_timeout=1000
```

Note the keepalive parameters at the end. For your reference, here's the explanation to those parameters:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html